# vue.js unit:test w test-utils and Jest : How can I test - window.open() in a method?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

In my component AudioPlayer I have a download() method :

```
download() {
  this.audio.pause();
  window.open(this.file, "download");
},
```

I can test the first line :

```
this.audio.pause();
```

But how can I test ( should I ? the second line :

```
window.open(this.file, "download");
```

Here is my current spec file test

```
  it("should open a window from downloadBtn", async () => {
    // jsdom doesn't support any loading or playback media operations. 
    // As a workaround you can add a few stubs in your test setup:
    window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype.pause = () => { /* do nothing */ };
    // given
    const wrapper = mount(AudioPlayer, {
      attachToDocument: true,
      propsData: {
        autoPlay: false,
        file: file,
        ended,
        canPlay
      }
    });
    const downloadBtn = wrapper.find("#downloadBtn");
    wrapper.vm.loaded = true; // enable downloadBtn
    // when
    downloadBtn.trigger("click");
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    // then
    expect(wrapper.vm.paused).toBe(true);
  });
```

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may replace `window.open` with a jest mock function and then test mock calls as usual.

```
window.open = jest.fn();
window.open('foo');
expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');
```

Comment: Good ! akl checked !

Answer (score 0):

you can check if `window.open` was called by

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(window, 'open');
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```